# Old Visual Studio project with ambiguous reference errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio

A client has given me an old (approx. 2010) .sln project for visual studio that they would like to have modified. The problem is that it is large and it now has a lot of errors in it from ambiguous references. The time it would take me to fix all the references is not worth the small change the client wants to make to the project. Is there a way of reverting this project so that I can open it without the errors? I have tried opening it in VS 2010 and VS 2013 but the errors are still there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No way, if the solution has issues you'll need to fix them all

Comment: Hi Matías, thank you for your answer